# Vec<Vec<T>> into Vec<T>

Tags: rust

```
let a = vec![ vec![1, 2], vec![3, 4], vec![5, 6] ];
```

How can I gather into a single `Vec` all the values contained in all the `Vec`s in `a` ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [flatten](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flatten) operator to remove the nesting of the vectors.

The following example is taken from the link.

```
let data = vec![vec![1, 2, 3, 4], vec![5, 6]];
let flattened = data.into_iter().flatten().collect::<Vec<u8>>();
assert_eq!(flattened, &[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
```

Answer (score 5):

Steve's answer is correct, but you should also know about [flat_map](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map) -- there's a good chance that that's what you really want to use, that it would make your code simpler and faster.  You probably don't need to ever create a Vec of Vecs -- just an Iterator of Iterators that you flat_map and then collect.

Answer (score -2):

[flat_map](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map) also flattens a vector of vectors.

```
let a = vec![vec![1, 2], vec![3, 4], vec![5, 6]];  
let merged = a.iter().flat_map(|s| s).cloned().collect::<Vec<i32>>();  
println!("{:?}", merged);

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=53286b800b1a562024ebbbe8ecc247c7)

Comment: Why not the simpler `flatten()`?